# Setting screensaver to "None" does not set "ScreenSaveActive" to "0"

Tags: windows-7, screensaver

The test OS is a Windows 7 Enterprise SP1.

I am referring to the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd405477%28v=vs.85%29.aspx --> "If you disable all screen savers by choosing (None) from the screen saver list, then the operating system deletes this entry from the registry and calls the SystemParametersInfo function with uiAction equal to SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE and uiParam equal to FALSE."

If you set the screensaver settings to "3D Text" and change it back later to "None", the "ScreenSaveActive" value in the registry is not set back to 0. It remains 1.

This behavior is not expected (as per documented). I have tried this on Windows XP and it works just fine.

Could anyone explain this behavior?

Thank you for your help.

Romain

Comment: Are you doing this through code? If so, show us the code. If not, then you're off-topic for SO.

Comment: Nowhere does that MSDN article talk about a registry key named "ScreenSaveActive".  You must use SystemParametersInfo() with SPI_GETSCREENSAVEACTIVE to check if a screen saver is active.  Note the GET.

Comment: No I am not using code, just using the Windows UI. For the ScreenSaveActive documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978620.aspx